# Website same on all screens

Tags: html, css, position

Okay, hello my name is Jordan. I have a website that needs to be the same on all screen sizes. I am using percentages which I think would work. So two questions...

1. How do I position a bottom/top tag with percentages(I tried and it did not work)
2. Also if the above will not work, what should I do to make it the same on every page.
3. If it does work, is there a easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Percentages won't work. One approach is to define min-width, min-height on the main div so that irrespective of screen size the page won't go smaller than the minimum size.

Comment: Well if I set the min-width to 800px and the min-height to 600px. Will that make sure it will not go smaller?

Comment: Yes, it will make sure it won't go below that size.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You may want to try using `em` units rather than percentages, and be sure not to use fixed widths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

By using Media Queries you may create a responsive website's layout by targeting desired screen resolutions.

For example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 320px) {
   div { background: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 700px) {
   div { background: green; width: 300px; height: 100px;  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1025px) {
   div { background: red; width: 600px; height: 100px;  }
}​
```